# Azure Devops pipeline to build .NET Framework Artifact multiple projects

Tags: .net, azure-devops, yaml, nuget, nuget-package

I am using Azure DevOps to build and package a .NET csproj with multiple project references. While the MSBuild task successfully compiles the csproj and includes all referenced projects in the bin\Release directory, the subsequent pack task does not include these referenced projects in the final NuGet package.

What works:

The msbuild command compiles the solution correctly, and the output in bin\Release contains all the necessary DLLs from the project references.

What doesn't work:

The NuGetCommand@2 command with the Pack target does not include all the necessary project references in the resulting NuGet package. Instead, only the output of the primary project is included.

What I've tried:

Using IncludeReferencedProjects=true with the Pack target, which should theoretically include the referenced projects in the NuGet package.
Inspecting the csproj files to ensure all project references are correct includint their paths.
Various configurations of the MSBuild task in Azure DevOps pipelines, including inline PowerShell scripts and YAML task definitions.

What I need:

I need the Pack target of the NuGetCommand@2 task to include the DLLs from the project references just as it appears in the bin\Release folder after a build.

Any insights or solutions to ensure that all referenced projects are included in the NuGet package when using Azure DevOps would be greatly appreciated.

```
    - task: NuGetCommand@2
       inputs:
         restoreSolution: '$(MainCsprojFile)'
       displayName: 'Restore NuGet Packages'
   
     - task: MSBuild@1
       inputs:
         solution: '$(MainCsprojFile)'
         platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
         configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
       displayName: 'Build with MSBuild'
   
     - task: NuGetCommand@2
       displayName: 'Pack NuGet package'
       inputs:
         command: 'pack'
         packagesToPack: '$(MainCsprojFile)'
         versioningScheme: 'off'
         versionEnvVar: 'PackageVersion'
         includeReferencedProjects: true
         outputDir: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
```

UPDATE ANSWERING please check the screenshot attached @wade zhou

[pipeline output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVRXW.png)

Comment: You might have better luck on a more appropriate exchange https://devops.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

As per the [nuget pack doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/cli-reference/cli-ref-pack):

[image]

Please check if you have `project named` `.nuspec` file on your project. If the file exists, it will invoke it in the nuget pack task:

[image]

You can:

1. temporarily remove the `.nuspec` file, with `includeReferencedProjects: true` in nuget pack task, check if it works. My pipeline result for your reference:

[image]

2. Or if you would like to keep the `.nuspec` file, please check if the `<files>`(dll name, path...etc) is correct.
   [image]

Comment: so first of all thanks for replying, I have checked the output of my pipeline and not using a .nuspec. the paths to the dll´s are also correct but only few dlls from the release folder are being taken and packed, there are more files which are not taken. the "-includeReferencedProjects doesn´t seem to include the rest of the .csproj file placed in the "principal" csproj file. all the references are inside it.
I went inside the agent and could see all the files I needed inside the \bin\release but the packing only includes 2 .dll

Comment: If you have all files in the `\bin\release`, you can create the main project named `.nuspec` file, define the files in the `<files>` section, so they will be added to the nupkg created, it should work. In addition, you can share the `<ProjectReference>` from main csproj in the statement.

Comment: On your new screenshot, it has the warning that `automatic package version and include referenced projects option do not work together`, could you check if you have correct setting on the task: `versioningScheme: 'off'`? and please remove `versionEnvVar: 'PackageVersion'` as it's not needed.

Comment: we need the packageVersion as it is set by comparing the existing packages on the feed and based on that we add one number up if version already existing or minor version number is being pushed. somehow I tried all of this by just using the "includeREferencedProjects" and having the versioningScheme: "off" still didnt work and on top of that the version fails as already exists as the one incoming is 1.0.0.0

Comment: all I see is that the \bin\release has all the correct archives there ready to be packed and the pack step only packs 2 of the archives

Comment: `versionEnvVar` is NOT the parameter of the nugetcommand task.  And the warning has indicated you cannot use automatic package version and include referenced projects option together. You have to disable the packageVersion.